# Is it possible to force a Type to be used only in static fields?

Tags: dart

I'm working on a library, and I have a implementation pattern users are required to follow:

```
class MyView extends LibView {
  static Foo f = Foo();

  @override
  void render(){
    use(f); // f should be static, otherwise things not work correctly
  }
  
}
```

I would like to tell the compiler that, if someone ever does this, it's incorrect:

```
class MyView {
  Foo f = Foo(); // Error: Foo can only be used in Static field.
  ...
}
```

Anyone know if this is possible? I find it really hard to find good docs on these sorta of language details when it comes to dart.

[EDIT] Since the "why" question always comes up, imagine something like:

```
class ViewState{
  Map<int, Object> props = {};
}
ViewState _state = ViewState();

class View {
   View(this.state);
   ViewState state;

   static int _key1 = getRandomInt();

   void render(){
      print(state(_key1))
   }
}

// These should both print the same value off of state since the 'random' int is cached
View(_state);
View(_state);
```

If the key's were not static, everything would compile fine, but they would not print the same results.

Comment: Why does `f` have to be static? I find this to be an odd thing to force and it's likely not directly possible, therefore it's not documented. Dart tends to have excellent documentation compared to many other languages. You might be able to use assertions, but it's impossible to say without knowledge of why it needs to be static.

Comment: It needs to be static because it enables a specific API implementation that is very clean and readable. Basically they are uses as keys, and should be the same for all instances of the class. If they are instance props, they can still be used as keys, but will be re-created for each instance, which we don't want.

Comment: Then they don't need to be static. They just have to be the same object.

Comment: Looks more like you should use a factory constructor to ensure you are returning the same instance of the object each time you are trying to create an instance (see singleton).

Comment: Updated the OP with another use-case. They need to be static, imagine something like:
`static int lookupKey1 = getRandomInt();`
If it's static, all instances of this class, share the same int for lookupKey1, if not they are all different. They need to be the same for the system to work correctly.

Comment: It still doesn't need to be static. Why give people the option to pass an object at all if you always want the same one?

Comment: It does, but I don't really want to argue back and forth about it when I know the entire design, and know that the use case is valid. It needs to be the same across all instances, it is not injected, it is auto-created and needs to be, something like `UniqueKey key1 = UniqueKey()` would not work because each instance gets a new key object. I need `static UniqueKey key1 = UniqueKey()`.

Comment: Because it's used as a lookup key, on another object that is passed around between instances. When they declare these keys, they are simply defining a list of keys that all instances of the class will agree to use.

Comment: Each instance can then do `this.thing.getItem(_key1)`, and as long as `thing` is the same, they will return the same data, even if `this` changes. With non-static key, `_key1` changes when instance changes and the whole pattern silently stops working.

Comment: Starting with the problem is probably easier. Imagine I had `enum MyViewProps { prop1, prop2 }` and I use those somehow in the view on a map `=> map[MyViewProps.prop1`. So, that works fine. Now, lets say I want to eliminate that boilerplate of the enum, completely... that's where I am. And that's where you end up at `static Key prop1 = Key()` and this should not change, instance to instance. If Key is not static, it's the equivalent of `=>map[getRandomKey()]`

Comment: Now you might say, why not just do `Key prop1 = Key("prop1")` which would also work, but now we're creating a vector for bugs, and more boilerplate. What we really want is just `static Key prop1 = Key()` which is bulletproof, but for the fact I can't restrict Key to be use statically.

Comment: And keep in mind I'm making a library, so am trying to make it as clean and easy to use for end-users. This is an effort to eliminate all possible boilerplate and make things error-proof from an end-use perspective.

Answer (score 0):

What you properly need are a singleton which can be created in different ways in Dart. One way is to use a factory constructor like this:

```
class Foo {
  static final Foo _instance = Foo._();

  factory Foo() => _instance;

  // Private constructor only used internally
  Foo._();
}

void main() {
  final a = Foo();
  final b = Foo();

  print(identical(a, b)); // true
}
```

By doing it like this, there will only be one instance of `Foo` which are then shared each time an instance are asked for. The instance are also first created the first time it is asked for since `static` variables in Dart are lazy and only initialized when needed.

Comment: I don't think this is it. These can be thought of more as dynamic enums , that a class can declare. `static UniqueKey prop1 = UniqueKey();`, `static UniqueKey prop2 = UniqueKey();` etc

Then, any instances of that class, when given some external map, will return the same item `getProp1<T>(map) => map[_prop1] as T`. It's basically used as a way to provide state, to a immutable class, by injecting the state.

The catch is that each implementing class defines it's own prop names / keys. `map` doesn't know anything about what it is holding other than it's a `Key<T>`

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to explain and what problem you are trying to solve. But the answer is "no" if the question is if you can get Dart to give a warning/error based on the context the object are used in.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much but you never know. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I just want to do the functional equivalent of
`int someUniqueKey = 0`, or `MyViewEnums.someUniqueKey` but do it with a typed object rather than a int/enym, like: `Object<Foo> someUniqueKey = Object<Foo>()`. In order for this to work with Objects, it needs to be static. It's similar to how `int someUniqueKey = random.nextInt(9999)` would have to be static in order to be used as a key that **all instances could share**. That way keys are auto-managed and unique, and people don't need to assign int's, strings, or whatever. It also has the advantage of letting me use the type later for compile time checks.

```
bool prop = getPropFromRef(_prop1Ref); //Will throw error prop1Ref is not Ref<bool>
```

I think I've figured out something that does the trick using darts package-level methods.

```
class Ref<T> {}
// Re-use existing ref if it already exists
Ref<T> getRef<T>(Ref<T> o) => o ?? Ref<T>();
class RefView {}

// In some other package/file:
class MyView extends RefView {
  static Ref<bool> prop1Ref = getRef(prop1Ref);
  static Ref<int> prop2Ref = getRef(prop2Ref);
}
```

This will make sure that prop1 and prop2 have the same values across all instances of `MyView` and it will throw an error if these are not static (since you can not pass an instance field before Constructor)

This still has the downside of a potential hard to spot error:

```
class MyView extends RefView {
  static Ref<bool> prop1 = getRef(prop1);
  static Ref<bool> prop2 = getRef(prop1); // passing prop1 to prop2's getRef, and they have the same<T>, compiler will miss it
}
```

But I think it might be preferable than having this potential error:

```
class MyView extends RefView {
  //Both of these will fail silently, keys will change for each instance of MyView
  Ref<bool> prop1 = getRef(prop1);
  Ref<bool> prop2 = getRef(prop2); 
}
```